# Ubuntu desktop, System Monitor, some process entries are missing on tree view, is it a bug?

Tags: system-monitor

On Ubuntu Linux 20.04.4 and 22.04.2, I see following symptoms.

From a Bash prompt, run `sleep 60 | sleep 70 &`, so that two new `sleep` processes appear on the system. However, when System Monitor app enables "Show Dependencies", ONLY ONE `sleep` entry is seen. I don't think it is the normal behavior.

Then I'd like to ask, is it a bug in System Monitor code? If it is, where is the official webpage to report the bug?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you're using those systems online, I'd suggest applying all security fixes asap, as your provided details show you're well behind. A fully upgraded 20.04 system will report as 20.04.6, and 22.04 will report as 22.04.3, so you're behind on applying all fixes.